# VBA Matching Row Height on Other Worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to using VBA/Macros on Excel and I ran into a problem with a project I am working on. I am having some issues with copying specific row heights for specific rows on one worksheet and applying it to all the other worksheets. I currently get a Type Error on the line:

Rows(Str(16 + intI) & ":" & Str(16 + intI)).RowHeight = MyArray(intI)

Can someone help me with fixing this error? Or if there are any other tips that someone can give me to make this simpler? Thanks!

Code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim MyArray(17) As String
Dim intI As Integer
Dim sh As Worksheet

For intI = 1 To 9
    MyArray(intI) = Rows(Str(16 + intI)).RowHeight
    Next

For intI = 10 To 17
    MyArray(intI) = Rows(Str(22 + intI)).RowHeight
    Next

' MsgBox Join(MyArray, vbCrLf) 'displays row heights in message box

For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    With sh.UsedRange
        For intI = 1 To 9
            Rows(Str(16 + intI) & ":" & Str(16 + intI)).RowHeight = MyArray(intI)
            Next
       For intI = 10 To 17
            Rows(Str(22 + intI) & ":" & Str(22 + intI)).RowHeight = MyArray(intI)
            Next
    End With
Next sh

End Sub
```

Comment: `Range.RowHeight` returns a `Double`. Why is `MyArray` declared `As String`?

Comment: `Rows(Str(16 + intI) & ":" & Str(16 + intI))` -> `Rows(16 + intI)`

Comment: @BigBen Thanks for the help! I can run the full script now, but the row heights on my other sheets aren't changing to match the first sheet.

Comment: You're not actually using the `With sh.UsedRange`.... but I'd get rid of it and just put `sh` in front of the `Rows` calls.

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! I am still a bit new to this, so I was just finding a bunch of code online tried to shape it into what I needed it to do.